# Air2.0, Error while accessing Native process API

Tags: javascript, html, air, air2

I am using native process API of Air2 in HTML/Js framework.

The problem comes when i try to make object of NativeProcessStartupInfo.

Here is mine code

```
if(air.NativeProcess.isSupported){

var nativeProcessStartupInfo = new air.NativeProcessStartupInfo();
```

Whenever i try to execute this code i got this error.

> TypeError: Result of expression
>   'air.NativeProcessStartupInfo' [] is
>   not a constructor.

Any suggestions on what i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your application.xml file. Make sure the name space is "http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/2.0", not "1.0". That screwed me over for a while...